# How correct Postgres plan in case of a double JOIN, ORDER BY and a LIMIT?

Tags: postgresql, index, order-by

I got a SQL request that takes more than 4s:

```
SELECT "Content"."contentId"
    FROM "UserFeed" 
    JOIN "FeedRole" ON "FeedRole"."feedId" = "UserFeed"."feedId" 
    JOIN "Permission" ON "Permission"."roleId" = "FeedRole"."roleId"
    JOIN "TagContent" ON "TagContent"."tagId" = "Permission"."tagId"
    JOIN "Content" ON "Content"."contentId" = "TagContent"."contentId"
    WHERE "UserFeed"."userId" = 600 ORDER BY "Content".title LIMIT 30;
```

This is due to the `ORDER BY`, so I create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "Content" ("title")
```

but postgres don't use it

If I split the request in two requests:

```
SELECT "Permission"."tagId"
    FROM "UserFeed" 
    JOIN "FeedRole" ON "FeedRole"."feedId" = "UserFeed"."feedId" 
    JOIN "Permission" ON "Permission"."roleId" = "FeedRole"."roleId"
    WHERE "UserFeed"."userId" = 600;
```

(take 81 ms)

and

```
SELECT "Content"."contentId"
    FROM "TagContent"
    JOIN "Content" ON "Content"."contentId" = "TagContent"."contentId"
    WHERE "TagContent"."tagId" IN (1584555, 2055170, 1868328, 1298378, 2021339, 1025073, 1254993, 1223241) ORDER BY "Content".title LIMIT 30;
```

(take 85 ms)

The second request use the index and everything is fine (less than 200ms is suffisant for our needs)

Question is: Is there a way to do that in one request ?

I test to do that:

```
SELECT "Content"."contentId"
    FROM "TagContent"
    JOIN "Content" ON "Content"."contentId" = "TagContent"."contentId"
    WHERE "TagContent"."tagId" IN (
        SELECT "Permission"."tagId"
            FROM "UserFeed" 
            JOIN "FeedRole" ON "FeedRole"."feedId" = "UserFeed"."feedId" 
            JOIN "Permission" ON "Permission"."roleId" = "FeedRole"."roleId"
            WHERE "UserFeed"."userId" = 600
    ) ORDER BY "Content".title LIMIT 30;
```

It takes more than 2s and it still don't want to use my index.

I also try to recompute statistics but there is no impact.

**EDIT:**

I finally manage to solve my problem with a materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "UserAuthorizedTag" AS 
    SELECT "UserFeed"."userId", "Permission"."tagId" FROM "UserFeed" 
        JOIN "FeedRole" ON "FeedRole"."feedId" = "UserFeed"."feedId"
        JOIN "Permission" ON "Permission"."roleId" = "FeedRole"."roleId";

CREATE INDEX ON "UserAuthorizedTag" ("userId", "tagId");
```

**EDIT2:**

I use approved answer.

**END EDIT**

Here are execution plans:

Big request

```
"Limit  (cost=16672.63..16676.13 rows=30 width=19) (actual time=4446.668..4446.700 rows=30 loops=1)"
"  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=16672.63..16710.66 rows=326 width=19) (actual time=4446.659..4446.688 rows=30 loops=1)"
"        Workers Planned: 2"
"        Workers Launched: 2"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=15672.60..15673.01 rows=163 width=19) (actual time=1542.963..1542.984 rows=11 loops=3)"
"              Sort Key: "Content".title"
"              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=34.06..15666.62 rows=163 width=19) (actual time=79.554..830.419 rows=199691 loops=3)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=33.63..15593.97 rows=163 width=4) (actual time=79.543..311.223 rows=199691 loops=3)"
"                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=33.07..15576.16 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=31.299..79.487 rows=3 loops=3)"
"                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=32.64..15574.71 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=31.143..79.292 rows=3 loops=3)"
"                                      Hash Cond: ("FeedRole"."feedId" = "UserFeed"."feedId")"
"                                      ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "FeedRole"  (cost=0.00..9639.95 rows=467495 width=8) (actual time=0.023..37.842 rows=373996 loops=3)"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=32.55..32.55 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.088..0.088 rows=8 loops=3)"
"                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                                            ->  Index Only Scan using "UserFeed_pkey" on "UserFeed"  (cost=0.43..32.55 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.050..0.080 rows=8 loops=3)"
"                                                  Index Cond: ("userId" = 600)"
"                                                  Heap Fetches: 8"
"                                ->  Index Only Scan using "Permission_pkey" on "Permission"  (cost=0.43..0.47 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.068..0.069 rows=1 loops=8)"
"                                      Index Cond: ("roleId" = "FeedRole"."roleId")"
"                                      Heap Fetches: 3"
"                          ->  Index Scan using "TagContent_tagId_idx" on "TagContent"  (cost=0.56..4.56 rows=137 width=8) (actual time=0.021..80.632 rows=74884 loops=8)"
"                                Index Cond: ("tagId" = "Permission"."tagId")"
"                    ->  Index Scan using "Content_pkey" on "Content"  (cost=0.43..0.45 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=599073)"
"                          Index Cond: ("contentId" = "TagContent"."contentId")"
"Planning time: 1.331 ms"
"Execution time: 4452.697 ms"
```

It appear that postgres underestimate the number of `TagContent` (expected 137, founded 74884)

Splitted first part:

```
"Gather  (cost=1033.07..16576.86 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=74.486..80.382 rows=8 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=33.07..15576.16 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=44.923..74.685 rows=3 loops=3)"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=32.64..15574.71 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=44.854..74.572 rows=3 loops=3)"
"              Hash Cond: ("FeedRole"."feedId" = "UserFeed"."feedId")"
"              ->  Parallel Seq Scan on "FeedRole"  (cost=0.00..9639.95 rows=467495 width=8) (actual time=0.026..36.309 rows=373996 loops=3)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=32.55..32.55 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.065..0.065 rows=8 loops=3)"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"                    ->  Index Only Scan using "UserFeed_pkey" on "UserFeed"  (cost=0.43..32.55 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.035..0.059 rows=8 loops=3)"
"                          Index Cond: ("userId" = 600)"
"                          Heap Fetches: 8"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using "Permission_pkey" on "Permission"  (cost=0.43..0.47 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.038..0.039 rows=1 loops=8)"
"              Index Cond: ("roleId" = "FeedRole"."roleId")"
"              Heap Fetches: 1"
"Planning time: 0.693 ms"
"Execution time: 81.619 ms"
```

Splitted second part:

```
"Limit  (cost=0.99..269.60 rows=30 width=19) (actual time=0.085..85.202 rows=30 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..5584336.55 rows=623690 width=19) (actual time=0.084..85.182 rows=30 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using "Content_title_idx" on "Content"  (cost=0.43..66833.22 rows=1198146 width=19) (actual time=0.034..0.294 rows=250 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Only Scan using "TagContent_pkey" on "TagContent"  (cost=0.56..4.60 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.338..0.338 rows=0 loops=250)"
"              Index Cond: ("contentId" = "Content"."contentId")"
"              Filter: ("tagId" = ANY ('{1584555,2055170,1868328,1298378,2021339,1025073,1254993,1223241}'::integer[]))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 87"
"              Heap Fetches: 21864"
"Planning time: 0.693 ms"
"Execution time: 85.263 ms"
```

It use "Content_title_idx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way that might force the plan you want is with this:

```
WITH T AS (SELECT "Permission"."tagId"
            FROM "UserFeed" 
            JOIN "FeedRole" ON "FeedRole"."feedId" = "UserFeed"."feedId" 
            JOIN "Permission" ON "Permission"."roleId" = "FeedRole"."roleId"
            WHERE "UserFeed"."userId" = 600
    )
SELECT "Content"."contentId"
    FROM "TagContent"
    JOIN "Content" ON "Content"."contentId" = "TagContent"."contentId"
    WHERE "TagContent"."tagId" IN (select "tagID" from t)
 ORDER BY "Content".title LIMIT 30;
```

---

Since that did not work, then try changing

```
WHERE "TagContent"."tagId" in ...
```

to be

```
WHERE "TagContent"."tagId" + 0 in ...
```

What this does is simply make it unable to use that index on "tagId".  So it is a more brute force solution where the finesse didn't seem to work.  Eventually PostgreSQL planner might get smart enough to see through this trick and realize that it can still use the index when adding zero to the column.  By the time that happens, hopefully it will also be smart enough so that the trick is no longer necessary in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, good idea but it result to a query during 2s and still sort data.

Comment: Ok, how about changing `WHERE "TagContent"."tagId" in ...` to `WHERE "TagContent"."tagId" + 0 in ...` ?

Comment: Thank you, It's work with `"TagContent"."tagId" + 0`. It's far simpler than maintain the materialized view.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if "FeedRole"."feedId" is already indexed? It seems that it takes long time to check this table on the first query.

Sometimes materialized views could be the solution to performance problems but it's preferible to solve them with indexes to not add more complexity (if possible).

Comment: Table "FeedRole" seems OK: `CONSTRAINT "FeedRole_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("roleId", "feedId")` and `CONSTRAINT "FeedRole_feedId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("feedId")`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you add the role_id on the join   "on" clause to feedrole table the query will use the pk Index. Another alternative could be create a new Index on feedrole only for feedid column. The idea is that join condition be the same as the Index columns.

If you create index remember to create concurrently to avoid locks.

Hope It helps